# minipage with itemize nested inside has different vspace at the end

Tags: itemize, minipage, enumitem

Here's the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{MyList}
{\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth} \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0em]}
{\end{itemize} \end{minipage}}

\noindent
\begin{MyList}
    \item item 1
\end{MyList}

\noindent
TEXT1

\noindent
\begin{MyList}
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
\end{MyList}

\noindent
TEXT2

\noindent
TEXT3

\end{document}
```

and here's the result

[image]

Clearly the second MyList with 2 items has less vspace at the end between TEXT2, comparing to the first MyList and TEXT1. But Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem ... What LaTeX version are you using ... For me, the space in the second case is much bigger due to your `\vspace{\baselineskip}`...

Comment: @koleygr sorry the \vspace{\baselineskip} was added later for testing, the code made the screenshot doesn't have that, fixed the question, thanks for pointing out. And it's built with command ```xelatex```, which has a weird version ```3.14159265-2.6-0.999991```.

Comment: I can't work out what is happening exactly without digging deep into the sources, but it's something to do with baselines! If you put `label=\strut\textbullet`, or just add a `\strut` to the last item, you get proper spacing. Does `enumitem` somehow add a strut to the first item but not later ones?

Comment: @Paul Stanley It works! I tried adding ```\strut``` before the ```\end{itemize}``` and the spacing was all good.